# How do I set a list column to its default value if it's not on the "New Item" form

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, custom-list, default-value

I am creating a project tracking list using Sharepoint-online.

I'd like the Status column to default to "Requested", so, in the column definition, I've set that as the default value from the list of available Status I've defined (Choice field, not a Lookup).

When I created a new "NewItem" form, I did not include the "Status" column. When I attempt to save the form, my validation fires telling me that some data is missing.

Unfortunately, the validation is supposed to trigger when `the Status column = "Migrate", not "Requested"`. The validation formula on the `Status` column is: `=AND(Status="Migrate",[DB Mods Required]<>"")` (`[DB Mods]` is a `Yes/No` column). This indicates to me that the Status column is not getting the correct default value from my NewItem form.

If I use the default NewItem form, I see that the proper default value (Requested) is set, and I can save the item without the validation triggering.

Comment: Did you customize your form in InfoWise or Designer?

Comment: if you are showing status field in new form it's working properly ? if yes try to hide this field with Jquery / javascript  ? also should you share your validation  ?

Comment: @ErinL - I used SharePoint Designer

Comment: @M.Qassas - I've added the validation formula to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes/No fields need to be treated as boolean. So you need to use a choice field if you want to require a choice.

With DB Mods Required as a radio button with Yes/No as options, try this validation formula: `=IF(AND([Status]="Migrate",ISBLANK([DB Mods Required]),false,true)`. This says that if Status is Migrate, but DB Mod Required has not been filled out, validation fails.

Comment: Since `[DB Mods Required]` is not a required field and doesn't have a default value, the intent of my validation is to ensure that it gets filled in when `Status = Migrate`. If `Status <> Migrate` then that field has no meaning. How would I check for that?

Comment: Setting a yes/no field to required doesn't do anything. It's `FALSE` if it's not checked, so that is its default value. I get around this by creating a choice field with radio buttons, no default value, and making it required. Then checking for not blank will work.

Comment: If I set it to required, I won't have to check for "not blank" because SharePoint will do that automatically, correct?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: The goal (though I may be pursuing the wrong one), is to leave it blank unless/until `Status = Migrate`. Not every task will require migration, and I don't want to have it defaulted to `No`, because it would be too easy to forget to toggle it to `Yes` when necessary.

Comment: With `DB Mods Required` as a radio button with Yes/No as options, try this validation formula: `=IF(AND([Status]="Migrate",ISBLANK([DB Mods Required]),false,true)`. This says that if Status is Migrate, but DB Mod Required has not been filled out, validation fails.

Comment: That did the trick! I asked the wrong question, but you managed to answer it anyway. Thanks!!

Comment: Actually, if you would change your answer to [this one](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191412/how-do-i-set-a-list-column-to-its-default-value-if-its-not-on-the-new-item-fo/191504#comment202141_191504), then the upvote & checkmark would be more appropriate, since the answer was really in the comments. Thanks for your help!